# How to avoid timeouts when saving a large number of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 4 app users can import data from a spreadsheet. The methods are loosely based on this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel)

A `save` function checks whether the import records are valid, displays errors if not, or saves if all records are valid.

```
def save
  if imported_records.map(&:valid?).all?
    imported_records.each do |record|
      record.save!
    end
    true
  else
    imported_records.each_with_index do |record, index|
      record.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
        errors.add :base, "Row #{index+2}: #{message}"
      end
    end
    false
  end
end
```

This works fine if the spreadsheet only contains a few records.

But on larger spreadsheets, the process exceeds the app's rack-timeout limit `Request ran for longer than 30000ms` (set to reflect Heroku limits).

The timeout occurs on `record.save`, probably because the model has some callbacks and calculations performed on save.

What is the best way to handle this?

- Users need to see error messages if imported records are invalid, so
  I don't want to move the entire import process to the background.
- I can't move the `record.save!` method into a background process because Sidekiq objects to being passed an unsaved object -  `Unable
  to create a Global ID for Record without a model id.`

Is there a simply way to iterate through these record saves in batches to avoid a long running process?

Answer (score 0):

I think the same question has been answered is the previous posts
reference :- [Prevent request timeout with long requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791580/prevent-request-timeout-with-long-requests)
please refere the post, i hope it helps :)